# Floating divs, how to make elements fit

Tags: html, css, css-float

I know about Masonry, but is really all of that needed in order to make the yellow item in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kq2eB/) move up into place to form a nice grid and fill that white space?

I feel like I'm missing some `CSS` ingredient.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block red">red</div>
  <div class="block blue">blue<br/>blue</div>
  <div class="block yellow">yellow<br/>yellow<br/>yellow</div>
</div>
```

The heights of these elements should be fluid.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kq2eB/

Comment: I don't think this is possible only with CSS if height is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still like to know if the original question is possible, but for now, I've split up my markup into 2 columns. So I'm going with this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block red">red</div>
    <div class="block yellow">yellow<br/>yellow<br/>yellow</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block blue">blue<br/>blue</div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kq2eB/5/

Comment: If it's usefull for you, use [more optimal](http://jsfiddle.net/bashirov/Kq2eB/6/)  :) . Every pair element add  float:right property.

Comment: What? That's the same fiddle link as above.

Comment: It's good, but you still need to know things about the divs for this to work, there is no pattern to your f-right class. For instance, if this popped out of a loop: http://jsfiddle.net/Kq2eB/7/.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a `top` and `position:relative` line and it seems to be where you might want it, you can play around with it though, I hope I have helped! Here's a fiddle!
http://jsfiddle.net/Ghpb6/

Comment: Forgot to mention, the heights of these elements can be dynamic, so setting a negative top value wouldn't work.

Comment: @Corey ok, Ill see what I can do!